# C# deserialized XML into class, then serialized into XML cannot return to class? Extra and misnamed fields

Tags: c#, xml, class, serialization, xsd

I know it sounds a bit odd.  And my team is trying to find another way around this with our clients and destination.  here is the scenario:

I started with an XSD, then built a C# class using XSD.exe.  Generally we use the WCF object interface and everything works great.  I have one client that needs to send us XML from the XSD format, and I am having issues converting the types as needed.

raw XML Data from client looks great! note some optional fields are not included:

```
 <Employees>
 <Emp>
  <FirstName>Ohio</FirstName> 
  <LastName>Test</LastName> 
  <ExternalID>11111111</ExternalID> 
  <SSN>999999999</SSN> 
  <IsHourly>true</IsHourly> 
  <HomeRestaurant>9992</HomeRestaurant> 
  <EmployeeType>Regular</EmployeeType> 
  <PayDeptID>2</PayDeptID> 
  <IsPrimary>false</IsPrimary> 
  <PayRate>5.00</PayRate> 
  <RemovePayRate>false</RemovePayRate> 
 </Emp>
```

I can de-serialize into my class and manipulate data as I need to, however currently I need to stream to my final destination, during re-serialize I get extra fields, and they are out of order (not sure if that matters):

```
 <Emp>
  <accountDisabledField>false</accountDisabledField> 
  <accountDisabledFieldSpecified>false</accountDisabledFieldSpecified> 
  <cityField>Independence</cityField> 
  <countyField xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <stateField>OH</stateField> 
  <street1Field>6200</street1Field> 
  <street2Field xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <zipField>44131</zipField> 
  </addressInfoField>
  <dateHiredField>0001-01-01T00:00:00</dateHiredField> 
  <dateHiredFieldSpecified>false</dateHiredFieldSpecified> 
  <dateOfBirthField>1977-01-25T00:00:00</dateOfBirthField> 
  <dateOfBirthFieldSpecified>true</dateOfBirthFieldSpecified> 
  <dateRehiredField>0001-01-01T00:00:00</dateRehiredField> 
  <dateRehiredFieldSpecified>false</dateRehiredFieldSpecified> 
  <dateTerminatedField>0001-01-01T00:00:00</dateTerminatedField> 
  <dateTerminatedFieldSpecified>false</dateTerminatedFieldSpecified> 
  <employeeTypeField>Regular</employeeTypeField> 
  <externalIdField>11111111</externalIdField> 
  <firstNameField>Ohio</firstNameField> 
  <forcePasswordChangeField>false</forcePasswordChangeField> 
  <forcePasswordChangeFieldSpecified>false</forcePasswordChangeFieldSpecified> 
  <homeRestaurantField xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <inTrainingField>false</inTrainingField> 
  <inTrainingFieldSpecified>false</inTrainingFieldSpecified> 
  <isHourlyField>true</isHourlyField> 
  <lastNameField>Test IT2</lastNameField> 
  <middleInitialField /> 
  <passwordExpireDateTimeField>0001-01-01T00:00:00</passwordExpireDateTimeField> 
  <passwordExpireDateTimeFieldSpecified>false</passwordExpireDateTimeFieldSpecified> 
  <passwordLockoutExpireDateTimeField>0001-011T00:00:00</passwordLockoutExpireDateTimeField> 
  <passwordLockoutExpireDateTimeFieldSpecified>false</passwordLockoutExpireDateTimeFieldSpecified> 
  <effectiveDateField>0001-01-01T00:00:00</effectiveDateField> 
  <effectiveDateFieldSpecified>false</effectiveDateFieldSpecified> 
  <isPrimaryField>true</isPrimaryField> 
  <payDeptIdField>1</payDeptIdField> 
  <payDeptNameField xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <payRateField>14.42</payRateField> 
  <removePayRateField>false</removePayRateField> 
  <effectiveDateField>0001-01-01T00:00:00</effectiveDateField> 
  <effectiveDateFieldSpecified>false</effectiveDateFieldSpecified> 
  <isPrimaryField>false</isPrimaryField> 
  <payDeptIdField>2</payDeptIdField> 
  <payDeptNameField xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <payRateField>5.00</payRateField> 
  <removePayRateField>false</removePayRateField> 
  </PayDepartment>
  </payDepartmentsField>
  <phoneNumbersField xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <sSNField>999999999</sSNField> 
  <stateCodeField xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <suffixField xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <termActionReasonField xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <termRehireEligibleField>false</termRehireEligibleField> 
  <termRehireEligibleFieldSpecified>false</termRehireEligibleFieldSpecified> 
  <userNameField xsi:nil="true" /> 
 </Emp>
```

That data cannot be deserialized back into the class!

Almost every field has the name 'field' appended to the actual name, and i have several new fields such as "xFieldSpecified" due to my optional/nullable fields.

here are my Serialize and DeSerialize methods:

```
    public static object DeserializeClassFromXML(string xml, Type t)
    {
        try
        {
            UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
            byte[] byteArray = encoding.GetBytes(xml);

            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(t);
            System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);
            System.Xml.XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            return xs.Deserialize(memoryStream);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log("Error deserializing class: " + e.Message);
            throw e;
        }
    }


    public static string SerializeClassToXML(object _object)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(_object.GetType());

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter(sb);

            s.Serialize(sw, _object);

            sw.Close();

            // Correct for the encoding type of the XmlSerializer
            return sb.ToString().Replace(@"encoding=""utf-16""", @"encoding=""utf-8""");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log("Error serializing class: " + e.Message);
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

I have recently found on Stackoverflow the ability to change the XML Attribute names using "Element Name", in the CS file, but what do I do with the extra fields?

Comment: Are you trying to exclude some properties from serialisation? There is an XmlIgnore attribute you can use if so.

Comment: I would also pay attention to the properties exposed by base types.

Comment: Can I correct my serialize so i get my base XML back?

Comment: Can you post your class please?